# Moving from state to state in this automaton via HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, automaton

I'm using this method to move from a state to the next on this automaton simulator:

```
public void processString (String string){


StringBuilder stepString= new StringBuilder (string);


int actualStateIntIndex;





 System.out.println("THE FOUND INITIAL ONE IS "+ theInitialStateIntIndex);


   State firstState = allStates.get(theInitialStateIntIndex);

  actualState = firstState;

   while (stepString.length()>0){

       Character characterToProcess = stepString.charAt(0);
       stepString.deleteCharAt(0);

       State nextState;
       nextState = ((State)actualState.get(characterToProcess)); // pasa al siguiente State
   actualState = nextState;

   actualStateIntIndex=allStates.indexOf(actualState);


   System.out.println("the actual state for " + stepString + " is " + actualStateIntIndex);

   if ((actualState.isFinal==true) && (stepString.length()==0))
      {
          System.out.println("THE STRING " + string + " IS ACCEPTED AT STATE " + actualStateIntIndex );

      }

   else if (stepString.length()==0 && (actualState.isFinal==false)){
          System.out.println("THE STRING " + string + " IS REJECTED AT STATE " + actualStateIntIndex);

      }

   }
```

}

Here:

```
State nextState;
nextState = ((State)actualState.get(characterToProcess));
```

I might be doing something wrong, but I don't get it.

The automaton gets stuck on state 0 always, although the StringBuilder is correctly being processed, why?

Here's the full code:

```
       package afd;

        import java.io.*;
        import java.util.*;

        /**
         *
         * @author Administrator
         */
        public class Main {

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            // TODO code application logic here

            FileReader fr = new FileReader("E://Documents and Settings//Administrator//My Documents//NetBeansProjects//AFD//src//afd//dfa.in");


            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            String firstLine= br.readLine();


            String [] firstLineSplitted = firstLine.split(" ");

            /*debug*/
            //System.out.println("firstLine is " + firstLine);

            int numberOfTestCases = Integer.parseInt(firstLine);

            for (int indexOfTestCases =0; indexOfTestCases < numberOfTestCases; indexOfTestCases++  ){

                int aux;
                System.out.println("Case Number " +  (aux = indexOfTestCases+1));

                String caseStartLine = br.readLine();

                /*debug*/
                //System.out.println("caseStarLine is " + caseStartLine);
                String [] caseStartLineSplitted = caseStartLine.split(" ");

                int numberOfStates;
                int numberOfAlphabetSymbols;
                int numberOfFinalStates;


                numberOfStates = Integer.parseInt(caseStartLineSplitted[0]);

                numberOfAlphabetSymbols = Integer.parseInt(caseStartLineSplitted[1]);

                numberOfFinalStates = Integer.parseInt(caseStartLineSplitted[2]);




                Automaton automaton = new Automaton();


                automaton.setAllStates(numberOfStates);

      //          automaton.size = numberOfStates;
     //           automaton.numberOfAlphabetSymbols = numberOfAlphabetSymbols;
     //           automaton.numberOfFinalStates = numberOfFinalStates;
                //Automaton a = new Automaton(numberOfStates);


                String alphabetLine = br.readLine();
                System.out.println("alphabetLine is " + alphabetLine);

                automaton.setAlphabet (alphabetLine);

    //            automaton.alphabetSymbols =new StringBuffer(alphabetLine);

                for (int indexOfStates = 0; indexOfStates < numberOfStates; indexOfStates++){

                      String transitionsLine = br.readLine();
                       /*debug*/
                       System.out.println("for the state " + indexOfStates + " transitionsLine is " + transitionsLine);

                       automaton.setTransitions(indexOfStates,transitionsLine);

                      /*String [] ijLineSplitted = ijLine.split(" ");

                      int i = Integer.parseInt(ijLineSplitted[0]);
                      int j = Integer.parseInt(ijLineSplitted[1]);
                        */

                }

                String finalStatesLine = br.readLine();
                /*debug*/
                System.out.println("finalStatesLine is " + finalStatesLine);
                String finalStatesLineSplitted [] = finalStatesLine.split(" ");

                automaton.markFinalStates(finalStatesLineSplitted);



                String initialStateAndNumberOfStringsLine = br.readLine();

                /*debug*/
                //System.out.println("initialStateAndNumberOfStringsLine  is " +initialStateAndNumberOfStringsLine);
                String [] splittedInitialStateLine = initialStateAndNumberOfStringsLine.split(" ");

                int initialState = Integer.parseInt(splittedInitialStateLine[0]);
                int numberOfStrings = Integer.parseInt(splittedInitialStateLine[1]);

                automaton.markInitialState(initialState);

                for (int stringIndex =0; stringIndex<numberOfStrings; stringIndex++){

                     String stringToProcess = br.readLine();
                     /*debug*/
                System.out.println("stringToProcess is " + stringToProcess);

                    automaton.processString(stringToProcess);


                }


             }
            }







    }


    class State extends HashMap<Character, State>{

    boolean isFinal;
    boolean isInitial;
    int stateId;

    State () {
        isInitial=false;
        isFinal = false;

        }

    public boolean equals (Object o){




        boolean isEqual = false;

        State compare = (State)o;

        if ((compare.stateId)==this.stateId)
        {

            return true;
        }

        return isEqual;

    }

    public int hashCode() {

        int theHashCode = stateId%7;

        return theHashCode;

    }


    }

      class Automaton{
         List <State> allStates;
        //private List<State> finalStates;
         int  theInitialStateIntIndex;
         State actualState;
          char [] alphabet;




        Automaton() {


            allStates = new ArrayList<State>();


        }public void setAllStates (int numberOfStates)  {

        for (int i =0; i <numberOfStates; i++) {

            State newState = new State();
            newState.stateId = i;
            allStates.add(newState);

         }

    }


    public void setAlphabet (String alphabetLine){

        alphabet = alphabetLine.toCharArray();




    }

    public void markFinalStates (String [] finalStates){

        for (int index =0; index<finalStates.length; index++) {

            int aFinalStateId = Integer.parseInt(finalStates[index]);

            State aFinalState = allStates.get(aFinalStateId);
            aFinalState.isFinal = true;
            allStates.add(aFinalStateId, aFinalState);


            /*DEBUG*/
            aFinalState = allStates.get(aFinalStateId);
            if ((aFinalState.isFinal)==true)
            System.out.println("THE STATE " + aFinalStateId + " IS MARKED AS FINAL");

        }

    }

    public void markInitialState (int initialStateId) {

            State theInitialState = allStates.get(initialStateId);
            theInitialState.isInitial=true;
            allStates.add(initialStateId, theInitialState);

            theInitialStateIntIndex = initialStateId;

            /*DEBUG*/

            System.out.println("THE INITIAL STATE ID IS " + initialStateId);

            theInitialState = allStates.get(initialStateId);
            if ((theInitialState.isInitial)==true)
            System.out.println("THE STATE " + initialStateId + " IS MARKED AS INITIAL");

    }


    public void setTransitions(int stateId, String transitionsLine){


            State theOneToChange = allStates.get(stateId);

            String [] statesToReachStringSplitted = transitionsLine.split(" ");

            for (int symbolIndex=0; symbolIndex<statesToReachStringSplitted.length;symbolIndex++){

                int reachedState= Integer.parseInt(statesToReachStringSplitted[symbolIndex]);

                theOneToChange.put(alphabet[symbolIndex],allStates.get(reachedState));

                System.out.println("THE STATE " + stateId + " REACHES THE STATE " + reachedState + " WITH THE SYMBOL " + alphabet[symbolIndex]);

            }

            allStates.add(stateId, theOneToChange);

    }


    public int findInitialState(){


        int index =0;

       cycle: for (; index<allStates.size(); index++){

            State s = allStates.get(index);

            if (s.isInitial==true) {

                break cycle;



           }
        } return index;

}



    public void processString (String string)
    {


        StringBuilder stepString= new StringBuilder (string);


        int actualStateIntIndex;



       System.out.println("THE FOUND INITIAL ONE IS "+ theInitialStateIntIndex);


       State firstState = allStates.get(theInitialStateIntIndex);

      actualState = firstState;

       while (stepString.length()>0){

           Character characterToProcess = stepString.charAt(0);
           stepString.deleteCharAt(0);

           State nextState;
           nextState = ((State)actualState.get(characterToProcess)); // pasa al siguiente State

           actualState = nextState;

           actualStateIntIndex=allStates.indexOf(actualState);


           System.out.println("the actual state for " + stepString + " is " + actualStateIntIndex);

           if ((actualState.isFinal==true) && (stepString.length()==0))
              {
                  System.out.println("THE STRING " + string + " IS ACCEPTED AT STATE " + actualStateIntIndex );

              }

           else if (stepString.length()==0 && (actualState.isFinal==false)){
                  System.out.println("THE STRING " + string + " IS REJECTED AT STATE " + actualStateIntIndex);

              }

           }



       }




    }
```

Here's the input file:

```
4
3 2 1
ab
1 0
2 0
2 0
2
0 3
abaa
aab
aba
3 3 2
ade
0 1 2
1 2 0
2 1 0
1 2
2 2
a
de
3 2 1
ab
1 0
2 0
2 0
2
0 3
abaa
aab
aba
3 3 2
ade
0 1 2
1 2 0
2 1 0
1 2
2 2
a
de
```

Edit: Here I'll explain the format for this input file

The first line represents the number of test cases.

Each test case starts with 3 integers, the first is the number of state for the automaton, next is the number of symbols in the alphabet and then the number of final states.

The next line is the alphabet. The symbols appear together.

Then there's a number of lines equal to the number of states that describe the transition function. The first line of this group of lines represents the transition function for the first state in the automaton (qo), the first element represents the state that's reached when the first symbol in the alphabet goes to this state, and so on. I had trouble understanding this from the original problem statement. This is the easiest way I've come to see it:

The lines:

```
1 0
2 0
2 0
```

equal:

```
            AlphabetSymbol0        AlphabetSymbol1
State0         State1                State0
State1         State2                State0
State2         State2                State0
```

Then there's a line that says which are the final states for the automaton.

Then comes a line which says which is the initial state and how many input strings will come.

Then come the lines with the input strings.

The output of this program should be:

C

```
ase Number 1
alphabetLine is ab
for the state 0 transitionsLine is 1 0
THE STATE 0 REACHES THE STATE 1 WITH THE SYMBOL a
THE STATE 0 REACHES THE STATE 0 WITH THE SYMBOL b
for the state 1 transitionsLine is 2 0
THE STATE 1 REACHES THE STATE 2 WITH THE SYMBOL a
THE STATE 1 REACHES THE STATE 0 WITH THE SYMBOL b
for the state 2 transitionsLine is 2 0
THE STATE 2 REACHES THE STATE 2 WITH THE SYMBOL a
THE STATE 2 REACHES THE STATE 0 WITH THE SYMBOL b
finalStatesLine is 2
THE STATE 2 IS MARKED AS FINAL
THE INITIAL STATE ID IS 0
THE STATE 0 IS MARKED AS INITIAL
stringToProcess is abaa
THE FOUND INITIAL ONE IS 0
the actual state for baa is 0
the actual state for aa is 0
the actual state for a is 0
the actual state for  is 0
**THE STRING abaa IS ACCEPTED AT STATE 2**
stringToProcess is aab
THE FOUND INITIAL ONE IS 0
the actual state for ab is 0
the actual state for b is 0
the actual state for  is 0
**THE STRING aab IS REJECTED AT STATE 0**
stringToProcess is aba
THE FOUND INITIAL ONE IS 0
the actual state for ba is 0
the actual state for a is 0
the actual state for  is 0
**THE STRING aba IS ACCEPTED AT STATE 1**
Case Number 2
alphabetLine is ade
for the state 0 transitionsLine is 0 1 2
THE STATE 0 REACHES THE STATE 0 WITH THE SYMBOL a
THE STATE 0 REACHES THE STATE 1 WITH THE SYMBOL d
THE STATE 0 REACHES THE STATE 2 WITH THE SYMBOL e
for the state 1 transitionsLine is 1 2 0
THE STATE 1 REACHES THE STATE 1 WITH THE SYMBOL a
THE STATE 1 REACHES THE STATE 2 WITH THE SYMBOL d
THE STATE 1 REACHES THE STATE 0 WITH THE SYMBOL e
for the state 2 transitionsLine is 2 1 0
THE STATE 2 REACHES THE STATE 2 WITH THE SYMBOL a
THE STATE 2 REACHES THE STATE 1 WITH THE SYMBOL d
THE STATE 2 REACHES THE STATE 0 WITH THE SYMBOL e
finalStatesLine is 1 2
THE STATE 1 IS MARKED AS FINAL
THE STATE 2 IS MARKED AS FINAL
THE INITIAL STATE ID IS 2
THE STATE 2 IS MARKED AS INITIAL
stringToProcess is a
THE FOUND INITIAL ONE IS 2
the actual state for  is 0
**THE STRING a IS ACCEPTED AT STATE 2** 
stringToProcess is de
THE FOUND INITIAL ONE IS 2
the actual state for e is 0
the actual state for  is 0
**THE STRING de IS REJECTED AT STATE 0**
```

I'm getting wrong all the lines written in bold.

I'm getting:

```
Case Number 1

THE STRING abaa IS ACCEPTED AT STATE 0
THE STRING aab IS ACCEPTED AT STATE 0
THE STRING aba IS ACCEPTED AT STATE 0


Case Number 2
THE STRING a IS ACCEPTED AT STATE 0
THE STRING de IS ACCEPTED AT STATE 0
```

My automaton is accepting everything and getting stuck on state 0, why?

Comment: Your code provided does not compile... some things are missing.  However, can you tell me how many states there are and if the value of stateID matters or if it can be anything?

Comment: Fixed. There are 3 states on each test case, there are two test cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure the problem is that State needs to override .equals(Object) and .hashCode().  I beleive allStates is a `List<State>` and to call get(State) on that List equals has to be overridden.

Comment: Yes, allStates is an ArrayList<State>. I'm inexperienced working with Collections, how should this overrides of equals() and hashCode() should be?

Comment: I fixed the code to make it compile. I don't understand why should I override equals and hasCode here. Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: when an object is looked up in a collection it calls the .equals method.  You can consider that the .equals from Object returns true if and only if the two objects are the same one (essentially o == o, or physical equality).  To check for logical equality (are the data members the same) you need to override .equals.  When you override .equals you have to override .hashCode() which is used in Maps along with .equals.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one thing the `processState` method doesn't seem to update the `currentState` field of the Automaton at all.  In fact, you don't seem to modify this anywhere.

It would help though if you explained what you're doing a little better.  You've just dumped a lot of uncommented source code and says "it gets stuck on state 0", even though we don't know what state 0 is or how this condition could be detected.  I'm *guessing* that currentState points to this, though the `State` instances don't have numbers either, so it's tough to know where to start analysing this...

At the very least, provide two bits of information (though more would be much better):

1. The field values/output you'd expect to see to indicate success, and what you're currently seeing (be *explicit* about the specific values of specific fields);
2. The place you would expect these fields to be updated and under what conditions.

Comment: Thanks, I've modified the code and question based on your suggestions. I've read about equals and hashCode from your links, but I still don't see how to make them work so the automaton doesn't get stuck on the state0.